# How to correctly type fn in this asyncHandler function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, controller

I'm using an `asyncHandler` function in my Express.js server backend to wrap my controllers. This `asyncHandler` helps in handling asynchronous operations without the need for try-catch blocks in every controller. The JavaScript implementation of this `asyncHandler` is as follows:

```js
const asyncHandler =
  (fn) => (req, res, next) =>
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);

export default asyncHandler;
```

Now, I'm trying to convert this piece of code into TypeScript for better typing and error handling, and I came up with the following code:

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

const asyncHandler = (fn) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => 
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);

export default asyncHandler;
```

However, TypeScript is throwing an error because I haven't typed the `fn` parameter, and currently, I'm unsure about the correct type that should be assigned to it. While using `any` for `fn` like below makes the code work, I am inclined to avoid `any` for better type safety and clarity:

```js
const asyncHandler = (fn: any) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => 
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
```

Could someone suggest a more specific and appropriate type for the `fn` parameter in this context? Your assistance would help enhance type safety in my Express.js project.